# How to increase Windows and/or Linux read cache size for process in C

Tags: c, windows, linux, caching

Is there a way to increase the cache read size for a process in C, in Windows and/or Linux?
I'm doing a lot of reading from disk. I only wish to do this for a single process and not globally. Is it possible?

If not, I will implement a custom caching functionality. Now, is there a way to find out which disk page a file position points to, and how large a page is, so that I can read the entire page and save it to memory?

Thanks! :)

Comment: First of all they are very different OS's. Linux will handling caching for you at the OS level. What are you trying to do. What exactly do you mean by a disk page? Are you attempting raw reads of a disk - I suggest never to do this.

Comment: Windows also handles caching at the OS level. When I start my program, it will at first run very fast. But as it continues, much of the cache is discarded by the OS because a lot of different disk pages are involved. If the cache size is increased, my program would run a lot faster.

Comment: What are you talking about. You give no file sizes/hardware specs. For example linux will copy you entire file into RAM and keep it there until it needs it for something more pressing. As @lgnacio says - use a memory mapped file if you want it in RAM, but if you have a 500PB file you are SOL most likely

Comment: File is about 1 GB. I don't want the entire file read into memory.

Answer (score 1):

Consider using a more efficient disk access method, such as `mmap()` and its Windows equivalent.

Answer (score 0):

You might consider using appropriately the following system calls on Linux: [mmap](http://linux.die.net/man/2/mmap) with [madvise](http://linux.die.net/man/2/madvise) `MADV_WILLNEED`; or [readahead](http://linux.die.net/man/2/readahead)